# Finding and displaying UTF-8 characters with xesearch

Tags: xetex, unicode, cjk, xecjk

The `xesearch` package allows one to replace text with other text. E.g.:

```
\documentclass{ctexbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xesearch}
\SearchList{list1}{newspaper}{book}
\begin{document}
    The book costs \$1.
\end{document}
```

When the document compiles, it reads, "The newspaper costs $1." When I tried other languages (e.g. `\SearchList{list1}{书}{book}`), it prints "The costs $1." (with a blank space where the character should appear), however, the document has no difficulty displaying the same character "书" elsewhere in the document.

How can I replace foreign characters?

Update:

The code manages to successfully replace the characters, however, the lines aren't breaking in the replacement text:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{ctexbook}
\pdfpagewidth=148mm
\pdfpageheight=210mm
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Adobe Song Std}
\setCJKmainfont{Adobe Song Std}
\usepackage{xesearch}
\SearchList{list1}{床前明月光，疑是地上霜。举头望明月，低头思故乡。}{poem}
\begin{document}
    \Huge
    \noindent 床前明月光，疑是地上霜。举头望明月，低头思故乡。 \\
    \noindent poem \\
\end{document}
```

Comment: Of course you have specified a font that *has* the `书` glyph, haven't you? Please, make a complete example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `\makexeCJKactive` at the beginning of the second argument of `\SearchList`. This works:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{ctexbook}
\pdfpagewidth=148mm
\pdfpageheight=210mm
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Adobe Song Std}
\setCJKmainfont{Adobe Song Std}
\usepackage{xesearch}
\SearchList{list1}{\makexeCJKactive 床前明月光，疑是地上霜。举头望明月，低头思故乡。}{poem}
\begin{document}
    \Huge
    \noindent 床前明月光，疑是地上霜。举头望明月，低头思故乡。 \\
    \noindent poem \\
\end{document}
```

Warning: I haven't looked into `xesearch` package to do enough tests. Any two different packages that use `\XeTeXinterchartoks` heavilly may not work together well. I'm not sure about `xesearch`.

Answer (score 5):

This works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Kai}
\usepackage{xesearch}
\SearchList{list1}{书}{book}
\begin{document}
    The book costs \$1.
\end{document}
```

[image]

The current font must contain the glyph. If it doesn't, then ask XeLaTeX to use one that does:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily{\kanjifont}{Kai}
\usepackage{xesearch}
\SearchList{list1}{{\kanjifont 书}}{book}
\begin{document}
    The book costs \$1.
\end{document}
```

[image]

(I've used a main font that shows more clearly the difference.)

For longer strings you have to reset the locale. At least with this code the result in the two lines is identical:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{ctexbook}
\pdfpagewidth=148mm
\pdfpageheight=210mm
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Kai}
\setCJKmainfont{Kai}
\usepackage{xesearch}
\def\1{\XeTeXlinebreaklocale "zh" \XeTeXlinebreakskip = 0pt plus 20pt\relax}

\SearchList{list1}{{\1床前明月光，疑是地上霜。举头望明月，低头思故乡。}}{poem}
\begin{document}
    \Huge
    \noindent 床前明月光，疑是地上霜。举头望明月，低头思故乡。 \\
    \noindent poem \\
\end{document}
```

But some expert in xeCJK might help better.

However, `xesearch` is not the right tool for this: a macro `\poem` expanding to 
`床前明月光，疑是地上霜。举头望明月，低头思故乡。` would be more useful.

Comment: The examples seem to have difficulty with kerning. For e.g., `\SearchList{list1}{书书书书书书书书书书书书书书书书书书}{book}` results in the characters running off the edge of the page,

Comment: @Village There's no hyphenation and no space between the Chinese characters, so this is normal, I'd say.

Comment: Chinese characters never have spaces between, but `xeCJK` or something should telling the characters to make a break.